# SSMA does not convert all my access tables to Azure

Tags: azure, data-migration, ms-access-2010

I have an Access project where the tables will be put up on Azure and then the database split so that the front end stays an Access form (I know not very high tech :) )  The problem is that when I used SSMA previously all the tables were found and everything worked nicely.  Since that time I have added more tables (to a fresh version of the program, not the one I already converted to Azure, that was just a test) but when I try the SSMA it only finds the newest tables.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a development question. It looks like an IT management problem. You can try to ask it on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite some time since I worked in Access, but are the tables that you have already ported to Azure in the Access database now linked tables in this Access Database?  If the tables are linked tables (meaning they are in another data source) then I would not expect SSMA to show them.

Also, I'd be very suspect of using Access with Azure in this manner.  The Access front end forms do not have retry logic built into them which means that in you get transient errors while attempting to save, read, etc. on these records it will not be handled well and you may end up in inconsistent states.  One option, besides moving away from Access as the front end if that is not an option, is to no rely on the binding the Access Forms give you and for you to manually write all the binding code handling transient errors; however, by the time you've done that you could have likely re-written the forms into a Web or Desktop app as well.
Article on Transient faults: http://windowsazurecat.com/2010/10/best-practices-for-handling-transient-conditions-in-sql-azure-client-applications/

Comment: Hello MikeWo, thanks for the response.  I deleted all the databases in Azure so I could start out fresh with migrating.  Could it be that for some reason my Access tables are remembering that they were migrated at one point in the past?  I have done this migration a few times and this is the first time it is not migrating all the tables.  I am going to check out that link you gave me.  The goal is to get this program onto the web but we needed it pretty quick and I know Access just well enough to get it up and running.  I really do appreciate the help! Andy

Comment: Did you create linked tables when you did the migration? See (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/04/13/migrating-access-jet-databases-to-sql-azure.aspx) for an example of this at the bottom of the article.  The reason I ask is because if the tables are linked tables in Access then the Access database itself doesn't contain the tables and I would think that SSMA would recognize this and not import them.